# when code android jni,met error "error: use of undeclared identifier 'open_memstream '"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I write a demo for read malloc_info,but meet an error
error: use of undeclared identifier 'open_memstream '

I include stdio.h,still not work
key words jni android open_memstream

Comment: which version of the NDK are you using? What android platform? How are you compiling this code?

Comment: The function in question is wrapped in `#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 23` (Android 6/Marshmallow), so are you compiling for at least that platform version?

Comment: @Botje you are right ,I fixed by add version thanks a lot